# Ubuntu Does not BOOT after Started GNOME

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, boot-repair, recovery-mode

Ubuntu stuck after

> [OK] Started GNOME

then nothing happens it doesn't even says what its doing next

I remember I deleted some ppa dependencies from Ubuntu Software Center
[image: from Ubuntu Software Center]
I don't know if this is causing the problem

I need a fix for this I have some important files on PC else I would have Reinstalled

Please reply soon :'(

Update:
I can boot into old version 5.0.0-31 not the default  5.0.0-32
can anyone fix it now for me?

Comment: Boot up with a live CD. This will allow you to copy your files to a safe backup drive. Then you can reinstall. Alternatively, you can boot into an emergency prompt then rescue your files using the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some important files on PC else I would have Reinstalled.

You can access the files on the drive using the Ubuntu installation media ISO. Simply boot from your installation media and *Try Ubuntu without installing*. From there, open the regular file manager, and in the devices pane on the sidebar, find your drive which had Ubuntu installed. Assuming it is not LVM and/or encrypted, you will be able to access all the files from here, and back them up to another drive before reinstalling. After backing up the necessary files, then you can safely reinstall from the same medium. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: I just discovered i can boot into 5.0.0-31 in advanced options... Does this help?

Comment: @MuditKumarSingh - can you boot the full desktop GUI? If not, you can drop to a root shell prompt and manually mount/copy from here.

Comment: I can boot in full gui... I guess it's an older version... I would be happy if this can be made to default

Comment: Keuboard does not work with The older version

Comment: @MuditKumarSingh - yep, this "older version" is an older version of the Kernel which is still installed, even after Kernel update. Running `sudo apt autoremove` will get rid of this Kernel version and the boot option, so it is not advised :). And you may need to use external USB keyboard if this is the case.

Comment: @MuditKumarSingh - I believe it is also possible to edit the grub menu options to be able to make it the default, although I'm not too sure on how to do this, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot into recovery mode.
 İfcannot , press e when boot menu change "quiet splash" to "text" hit ctrl+x
as told here :http://ask.xmodulo.com/boot-into-command-line-ubuntu-debian.html
then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge gnome
sudo apt-get install gnome
sudo reboot
```